# Dropwizard and c3p0 integration

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard, c3p0

Is there any way to use c3p0 as the connection provider to the dropwizard Hibernate repository? 
I added the properties of c3p0 to the dropwizard configuration file but I don't think it did something.. 
Also,  I added the Hibernate c3p0 dependency to the pom file

Comment: https://github.com/mtakaki/dropwizard-hikaricp - A sample code for integrating HicariCP as a database connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm hardly expert here, your question is the first time I've encountered dropwizard.

But a quick look at its code suggests that it relies on a [DataSourceFactory](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-db/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/db/DataSourceFactory.java) which is hardcoded to use tomcat-jdbc Connection pool.

However, since it [looks like](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/manual/hibernate.html) you configure hibernate (and othe db-dependent modules) directly by constructing your own `DataSourceFactory`, and since that class is nonfinal, I think you could just write your own subclass and override its build method to return a suitably configured c3p0 DataSource, or (more easily), let the c3p0 DataSource pick up its configuration from a `c3p0.properties` file (or any of the several configuration styles c3p0 supports). The inherited getters and setters would then be meaningless -- those properties would be ignore, and attempts to configure the DataSource with dropwizard's json or yaml tools would be ignore. (You might override those getters and setters to throw an Exception to remind you that they are not implemented, but you'd have to verify that they don't get called even if you don't explicitly configure them.) The only hard part would be to configure the `MetricRegistry`, I presume to keep and monitor stats about the pool that interest you. But this wouldn't be too hard: See the start() method of [ManagedPooledDataSource](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-db/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/db/ManagedPooledDataSource.java) for a template, and all the stats you can monitor on a c3p0 [PooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html).

You may not need to extend DataSourceFactory. It might be sufficient to just write a separate class that implements [PooledDataSourceFactory](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-db/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/db/PooledDataSourceFactory.java). Plus, there's a class called [DatabaseConfiguration](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-db/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/db/DatabaseConfiguration.java) whose last commit message is "Add facility to plug-in custom DB connection pools." But I can't find any examples or documentation of this class. It's pretty clear how you could integrate c3p0 by just extending DataSourceFactory, and others have [suggested that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/lxjcE7vZqUU).